# Change View by clicking on Column

Tags: sapui5

I'm new in SAPUI5 and i create a Table like in this Example -> [Demo Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html) . Now i want to create a "link" on the table columns. For Example by clicking on LastName "Ander" the app changes the view to "ander view". How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a link as shown below

```
var oLink1 = new sap.ui.commons.Link({
text: "Link to Action", 
tooltip: "This is a test tooltip",
press: function() {
    //to go to external link use below code
    window.location.replace("http://mywebsite.com/nextPage.html");

    //to change the view use this
    var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idSecondPage", viewName:"project.secondPage", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
    view .placeAt("sample1"); 

});
```

Now add it in table column in template

```
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Web Site"}),
    template: oLink1
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all: what did you try until now?

second: in general i am using jQuery for that
e.g.:

```
$(viewToHide).fadeOut();
$(viewToShow).fadeIn();
//or use any other of the hide/show functions for that
```

where the two variables are the ids of the specific views, for example `#anderView`